# Не работает http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache"

Tags: html

Ребята помогите пожалуйста, не могу отключить кэширование сайта.

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="max-age=3600, must-revalidate" />
```

Почему этот код не работает ?

Comment: Например, потому что вторая строка включает кэширование?

Comment: Главная задача состоит в том чтобы сайт показывал обновления на стороне клиента. А кроме как нажать Ctrl + F5 ниче не работает. Я пробывал и без второй строки.